# Implement routing with steps component in a dynamic dialog priemng

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, primeng, angular-routing

Could anyone help me with implementing a steps component in a dynamic dialog in primeng. I am working on a sample project where I need to implement login screen in a dialog box that includes multiple steps like entering basic information in first step and then entering more details about the user in next steps.

I would like to navigate to different components as I move from one step to another while staying in the dynamic dialog box.

Any general directions is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is achievable this way:

Root App component bootstraping:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    /**
     * DialogService must be provided in the component that is about to open the dialog - the component injector is taken in order to keep router-outlets in the right order
     */
    // DialogService,
    provideAnimations(),
    provideRouter([
      {
        path: '',
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('./components/my-page/my-page.component').then(
            (c) => c.MyPageComponent
          ),
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'step-one',
          },
          {
            path: 'step-one',
            loadComponent: () =>
              import(
                './components/my-page/steps/1-step-one/step-one.component'
              ).then((c) => c.StepOneComponent),
          },
          {
            path: 'step-two',
            loadComponent: () =>
              import(
                './components/my-page/steps/2-step-two/step-two.component'
              ).then((c) => c.StepTwoComponent),
          },
          {
            path: 'step-three',
            loadComponent: () =>
              import(
                './components/my-page/steps/3-step-three/step-three.component'
              ).then((c) => c.StepThreeComponent),
          },
        ],
      },
    ]),
  ],
});
```

Style.scss:

```
@import 'primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css';
@import 'primeng/resources/primeng.css';
@import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
@import 'primeflex/primeflex.css';
```

Page component that will show the dialog:

```
<ng-container
  *ngIf="dynamicDialog; else dialogTpl"
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="dynamicDialogTpl"
></ng-container>

<ng-template #dialogTpl>
  <button
    type="button"
    (click)="showDialog()"
    pButton
    icon="pi pi-info-circle"
    label="Show dialog"
    [disabled]="dialogVisible"
  ></button>
  <p-dialog position="top" [(visible)]="dialogVisible">
    <app-steps-dialog></app-steps-dialog>
  </p-dialog>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #dynamicDialogTpl>
  <button
    type="button"
    (click)="showDynamicDialog()"
    pButton
    icon="pi pi-info-circle"
    label="Show dynamic dialog"
    [disabled]="dynamicDialogVisible"
  ></button>
</ng-template>

@Component({
  templateUrl: './my-page.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    ButtonModule,
    DialogModule,
    StepsDialogComponent,
    NgIf,
    NgTemplateOutlet,
  ],
  /**
   * DialogService must be provided in the component that is about to open the dialog - the component injector is taken in order to keep router-outlets in the right order
   */
  providers: [DialogService],
})
export class MyPageComponent implements OnInit {
  /**
   * a switch between dialog an dynamicDialog
   */
  dynamicDialog = true;

  dialogVisible: boolean = true;
  dynamicDialogVisible: boolean = false;

  private destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);
  private dialogService = inject(DialogService);

  private dynamicDialogRef: DynamicDialogRef | undefined;

  private viewContainerRef = inject(ViewContainerRef);

  ngOnInit() {}

  showDialog(): void {
    if (!this.dynamicDialog) {
      this.dialogVisible = true;
    }
  }

  showDynamicDialog(): void {
    if (this.dynamicDialog) {
      this.dynamicDialogVisible = true;
      this.dynamicDialogRef = this.dialogService.open(StepsDialogComponent, {
        appendTo: this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement,
        data: {
          dynamic: true,
        },
      });
      this.dynamicDialogRef.onClose
        .pipe(
          tap(() => {
            this.dynamicDialogVisible = false;
            this.dynamicDialogRef = void 0;
          }),
          takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)
        )
        .subscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Steps Dialog Component:

```
<div class="card">
  <p-steps [model]="items" [readonly]="false"></p-steps>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

@Component({
  selector: 'app-steps-dialog',
  templateUrl: './steps-dialog.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [StepsModule, ButtonModule, RouterOutlet],
})
export class StepsDialogComponent {
  items: MenuItem[] = [
    { label: 'Step One', routerLink: 'step-one' },
    { label: 'Step Two', routerLink: 'step-two' },
    { label: 'Step Three', routerLink: 'step-three' },
  ];

  dynamicDialogConfig = inject(DynamicDialogConfig, { optional: true });

  constructor() {
    console.log('dynamicDialogConfig', this.dynamicDialogConfig);
  }
}
```

Step One component:

```
<h2>Step One</h2>
<div class="flex justify-content-end">
  <p-button icon="pi pi-chevron-right" routerLink="/step-two"></p-button>
</div>

@Component({
  templateUrl: './step-one.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterLink, ButtonModule],
})
export class StepOneComponent {}
```

Step Two component:

```
<h2>Step Two</h2>
<div class="flex justify-content-between">
  <p-button icon="pi pi-chevron-left" routerLink="/step-one"></p-button>
  <p-button icon="pi pi-chevron-right" routerLink="/step-three"></p-button>
</div>

@Component({
  templateUrl: './step-two.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterLink, ButtonModule],
})
export class StepTwoComponent {}
```

And Step Three component:

```
<h2>Step Three</h2>
<div class="flex justify-content-start">
  <p-button icon="pi pi-chevron-left" routerLink="/step-two"></p-button>
</div>

@Component({
  templateUrl: './step-three.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterLink, ButtonModule],
})
export class StepThreeComponent {}
```

And the last but not least :)
[stackblitz@demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1i8etq)

Comment: Thank you very much. Can the above be achieved using the dynamic dialog component from Primeng.

Comment: @shashankhr why DialogService? This seems inefficient.

Comment: It is not inefficient, but a preference so as to be easily inject a modal in a component and use the built in methods provided by the dialog service.

Comment: it is inefficient from the code simplicity perspective. I am not sure it is possible to combine DynamicDialog and Routing. Let me check it.

Comment: Ok, it works :) But it is important to provide `DialogService` in a component that is to open the dialog because thie dialog instance take an `injector` from the service instance and nested router outlets depent on it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate the help. It seems like with the dyanmic dialog approach the components are nested wherein the parent component is also injected and the view includes steps component and the parent component in it leading to the steps view not displayed properly. In your stackblitz demo, I can see that the show dynamic dialog button is nested. Is there a way we could resolve this by using named router outlet ?

Comment: Ohhh it is because my stackblitz project got forked somehow :P And the link has changed. I have updated the link in the answer. Check it out again please.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1i8etq

Comment: Enjoy bro and keep going on learning Angular stuff :)